# Browser print, doesn´t show images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, printthis

I'm trying to print some "chosen" content on my webpage with printThis jQuery plugin. When I press `print_btn`, no images or `<hr>` are shown in the print. Why?

**HTML**

```
<button id="print_btn"></button>
<div class="elementBricka display" style="page-break-after:always">
    <div class="lkbLoggo"></div>
    <hr>
     ....
```

**CSS**

```
#elementBrickor{
    align-items: center;
}

.elementBricka{
    width: 9.614cm;
    height: 14.404cm;
    border: 1px solid;
    background-color: white;

    float: none;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.lkbLoggo{
    width: 9.182cm;
    height: 2.721cm;
    margin-top: 0.199cm;
    background-image: url("/img/lkb_logga2.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#print_btn').click(function () {
        $('.display').printThis({
            debug: true,
            importCSS: true,
            importStyle: true,
            loadCSS: "/Data.css",
            pageTitle: false,
        });
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

I´ll answear my own question.
This has nothing to do with "PrintThis".
It´s a browser "issue".
But it was easy fixed with adding: `!important` in my Css file where i load the img.

Comment: Images should be printing - do you have an example page? I am the printThis author, so I would like to track down any bugs.

Comment: Here's a demo showing that images work: http://jsbin.com/lelefihowe/edit?output

Comment: @Jason all i had to do was to add "!important" in my CSS where i load the img. So, it´s not a "PrintThis" issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so there is no way to make "PrintThis" print my images.
But i found a way in CSS:

```
.lkbLoggo{
    width: 9.182cm !important;
    height: 2.721cm !important;
    margin-top: 0.199cm !important;
    background-image: url("/img/lkb_logga2.png") !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    background-position: center !important;
}
```

Just add `!important`after each line and it shows in the print.
Now.. i´d like a funktion to make a whole class important, instead of adding it to every row.

Answer (score 2):

My solution was to implement

> -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;

Comment: Amazing! This is the only solution that work for me..and it it's the most simple way!

Answer (score 1):

images generally do not print, as this is a setting in the browser.

Go to Tools / Internet Options /Advanced / and make sure that "Print Background and Images" is ticked.

However, there's no workaround to get images to print with printThis plugin.

If you want to try print image with jquery you can do like this : http://jsfiddle.net/8dXvt/626/

```
function nWin() {
  var w = window.open();
  var html = $("#toNewWindow").html();
  /*for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
  $("#toNewWindow").clone().prependTo("body")
 }*/
 $(w.document.body).html(html);
 setTimeout(function(){w.print()}, 1500);
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Thank you.

Comment: I found `!important` to do my work. This is better because it will work in every browser without changing any options in the browser. Thank you.

Comment: Images do work for printThis - Here's a demo showing that images work: http://jsbin.com/lelefihowe/edit?output

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.display').printThis({
base='true'
});
```

try this