# i want to print the model box

Tags: reactjs, printing

i want to print the model box of the page but without the print button itself. I have tried this code but it didn't work. I am new to react . help.

the code is as below:

```
import React from "react";
import "./Bill.css";
import logo from "./images/logo.png";
import { Link, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import ClientDashboard from "./ClientDashboard";
import BillTable from "./BillTable";

function Bill() {
  const history = useHistory();

  const logout = (e) => {
    localStorage.removeItem("token");
    history.push("/");
  };

  if (!localStorage.getItem("token")) {
    history.push("/");
  }

  return (
    <div className="modal__bill">
      <div className="bill__navbar">
        <Link to="/clientdashboard" className="header__link">
          <img className="navbar__logo" src={logo} alt="logo" />
        </Link>
      </div>
      <div className="box">
        <BillTable />
        <button className="print__button" onClick={() => window.print()}>
          Print
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Bill;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to hide the button by css?

> [How do I hide an element when printing a web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355313/how-do-i-hide-an-element-when-printing-a-web-page)

In your case you can add

```
@media print {
  .print__button {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: the button is hidden and i want the model popup only to be printed instead of the whole page...

Comment: how can i do it inline?

Comment: unfortunately no
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808233/is-it-possible-to-put-css-media-rules-inline

but you can create more reusable css class like .hidden-print and add it to className of button

Comment: can i only print the div className=box in A4.

Comment: I guess it's because of img. Try one of those
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33912878/browser-print-doesn%C2%B4t-show-images